# Nested UIViewController does not respond to device rotation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sdk, uiviewcontroller, rotation

I'm developing an app using a fork of LeavesViewController that changes to a two-page orientation when the device turns to landscape.

When using the Leaves controller alone, everything works fine.

When using the Leaves controller inside the view of my main UIViewController, it never gets any of the device rotation messages (however my main UIViewController does).

What can I do to make the Leaves controller reaceive the device rotation messages?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not supposed to nest UIViewControllers like that. In practice you can, but they're not managed by UIKit so you lose the functions that are usually called by the framework (viewWillAppear: and friends, I think).

You can forward the rotation methods yourself.

Comment: I know but then I should adapt the LeavesViewController to be an UIView and I'm too lazy hehe.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but how do you forward the rotation ? The only function I found are notification functions, not a rotateView or this kind of thing

Comment: @CedricSoubrie: In your main controller, override the methods and call them on the child VC. Getting this right is quite difficult, especially since method ordering occasionally changes between OS releases (especially -view{Will,Did}{Appear,Disappear}:, which sometimes get called automatically!).